# MongoMapper returns empty document set on call to `all`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a collection in `mongodb`:

```
> use my_db
switched to db my_db
> db.my_coll.count()
278
```

I have a class in ruby:

```
class MyColl
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :fst, Integer
  key :sec, Float
end
```

When I call:

```
MongoMapper.database = 'my_db'
MyColl.count
#=> 0
```

though I definitely expected to receive the same result as in mongo console. No errors, no nothing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoMapper`'s `ActiveRecord` convention expects class name to correspond collection name as:

```
self.class.name.gsub(/::/, '.').underscore.pluralize == coll_name
```

That said, class `MyColl` expects the underlying collection to be named `my_colls`. Despite that there is no such collection in the database, `MongoMapper` silently assumes the user wants to create this collection transparently. That's why `MyColl.count` returns zero, rather than throws an exception.

```
> db.my_coll.renameCollection("my_colls")
```

will do the trick.